# How can I reliably update a String in SwiftUI based on a @Published Array from an ObservableObject?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I’m building a macOS app based on data from CloudKit. I’m running into an issue where one of the `String`s in my UI is not being updated as I would expect it to.

## Model

I have an `Event` `struct`, which has an ID and a timestamp:

```
struct Event: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: UUID
    let timestamp: Date
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(),
         timestamp: Date) {
        self.id = id
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}
```

Periodically, my app fetches updated `Event` data from CloudKit. This is handled in an `ObservedObject` called `DataStore`.

For example, the fetch happens when the `DataStore` is initialized, and when a push notification comes from the server to indicate there is new information.

The function `updateLocalEvents()` in `DataStore` is called to actually update the local in-memory `@Published` `Array`, which calls `fetchEvents()` to actually get the current set of last 10 events data from CloudKit.

```
class DataStore: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var recentEvents: [Event] = []
    
    init() {
        
        updateLocalEvents()
    }
    
    func updateLocalEvents() {
        
        print("updateLocalEvents()")
        
        fetchEvents()
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: &$recentEvents)
    }
    
    private func fetchEvents() -> AnyPublisher<[Event],Never> {
        
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Event",
                            predicate: predicate)
        
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp",
                                                  ascending: false)]
        
        let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        operation.resultsLimit = 10
        operation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
        
        var events = [Event]()
        
        operation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
            
            if let id = UUID(uuidString: record.recordID.recordName),
               let timestamp = record.object(forKey: "timestamp") as? Date
            {
                events.append(Event(id: id,
                                timestamp: timestamp))
            }
        }
        
        return Future<[Event],Never> { promise in
            
            operation.completionBlock = {
                promise(.success(events))
            }
            
            CKConstants.container
                .privateCloudDatabase
                .add(operation)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

## View

In my view, I show a `String` to indicate the time since the last event. For example, it may say *1 hour ago* or *3 hours ago* using a `RelativeDateTimeFormatter`.

This is stored in a `timeAgo` `@State` variable of type `String?`.

There is a `Timer` that attempts to update the `timeAgo` `String?` every minute, using an `.onReceive` modifier for the `Timer`, and another `.onReceive` modifier that uses the `@Published` `Array` of `Event`s to update the `timeAgo` `String?`. Here is my view code:

```
struct EventsView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var store: DataStore
    
    @State private var timer: Publishers.Autoconnect<Timer.TimerPublisher> = Timer
        .publish(every: 60,
                 on: .main,
                 in: .common)
        .autoconnect()
    
    @State private var timeAgo: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            if let mostRecentEvent = store.recentEvents.first {
                
                Text(timeAgo ?? relativeTimeFormatter.localizedString(for: mostRecentEvent.timestamp, relativeTo: Date()))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.system(.largeTitle,
                                  design: .rounded))
                    .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                        timeAgo = relativeTimeFormatter
                            .localizedString(for: mostRecentEvent.timestamp, relativeTo: Date())
                    }
                    .onReceive(store.$recentEvents) { recentEvents in
                        print(".onReceive(store.$recentEvents)")
                        if let mostRecentEvent = recentEvents.first {
                            timeAgo = relativeTimeFormatter
                                .localizedString(for: mostRecentEvent.timestamp, relativeTo: Date())
                        }
                    }
            } else {
                Text("No Event Data")
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 250,
               maxWidth: 250,
               minHeight: 200,
               maxHeight: 200)
    }
}

private let relativeTimeFormatter: RelativeDateTimeFormatter = {
    let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
    formatter.dateTimeStyle = .numeric
    return formatter
}()
```

The problem is that, sometimes, there is a push notification indicating new data, and the `updateLocalEvents()` function is called, updating the `recentEvents` variable, which also triggers `.onReceive(store.$recentEvents)`. I can see this is happening with my `print` statements. However, the `timeAgo` variable does not always get updated, and the view still shows the old string.

How should I change this to get my desired result of always keeping the `timeAgo` `String?` up-to-date based on the current value of `@Published var recentEvents`?

I’m also open to any other suggestions to simplify or improve any of this code I shared! Thanks!

Comment: For iOS 15+ [`TimelineView'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview) is the best way to refresh the screen based on time

Comment: @loremipsum I'm aware of TimelineView, but I'm trying to target earlier versions of macOS and iOS with this code. What would be a good way to do this without using TimelineView?

Comment: Shot in the dark, I suspect the view isn't changing based on the new updated information. So I would add `.id(timeAgo)` just after the text that has `.onReceive` If it works let me know.

Comment: May be missing something, but is it not actually working correctly? That is `.onReceive(store.$recentEvents)` is getting `recentEvents[Event]`s. That array  can be empty. And when that occurs then, there's not going to be a recentEvents.first to get a timestamp from to update `timeAgo ` with.

Try giving the `if let mostRecent ...` an `else` branch with a debug print in it in the `onReceive` to see if it is an empty array causing prob.

Comment: Try adding a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block around the point where you set `timeAgo` in the `onReceive` for `(store.$recentEvents)`.  My theory is that the view is already in a update cycle because of changes to its state and so this other state change gets lost.  By delaying the state update to the next event cycle, maybe it will be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I made a dumb mistake and posted this thinking it was a SwiftUI or Combine issue, when really there was a different problem.

From what I can tell now, SwiftUI and everything I had set up was actually working fine.

**The real issue was in the data I was fetching. The array of `Event`s based on the query results were not what I expected.** I was receiving a push notification from CloudKit that indicated there were, and based on that I would kick off the query to CloudKit to fetch the new data. This data that was fetched was outdated, and did not include the new events (or still included deleted events).

I found that if I included a delay of just a couple seconds between the notification arriving and sending the query, the expected data would come back from CloudKit and everything would update accordingly.

I should have actually been using the `CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation` and related features of the CloudKit API to fetch and process the actual changes that triggered the notification instead of kicking off a fresh query each time.